# How to run the python file in Spark

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

I am having python code in python file.I want to know how to run the python code which is present in one location.I am using Ubuntu OS.In my code, I am getting Json from one URL and need to show as scatter graph using SPARK.I am new to PYSPARK. Please guide me how to achieve this. Please find my below code,

```
`﻿import multiprocessing
import time
import json
from sseclient import SSEClient as EventSource
# 'Complete your function here i cant understand what you are doing'
# i just placed the code inside check once i dont have the package so u try it
def func(n):
    file = open('w.txt','w',encoding='utf8')
    url = 'https://stream.wikimedia.org/v2/stream/recentchange'
    print(1)
    url = 'https://stream.wikimedia.org/v2/stream/recentchange'
    json_st=''
    stt=''
    for event in EventSource(url):
        if event.event == 'message':
            try:
                change = json.loads(event.data)
            except ValueError:
                pass
            else:
                print(1)
                file.write(str(event.data))
                #if file.write(str(event))count <= 10:
                #print(event.data)
                #print(event.data)
                #js=json.loads(event.data)
                ##print(js['comment'])
                #file.write(stt)
                #print(stt)
                #file.write(str(event))
                #    count = count + 1
                #else:
                #    break
    #print(stt)
    #json_str={s}


if __name__ == '__main__':
    # Start your process as a process
    p = multiprocessing.Process(target=func, name="func", args=(10,))
    p.start()

    # Wait 3(give your time in secs) seconds for foo
    time.sleep(3)

    # Terminate func
    p.terminate()

    # Cleanup
    p.join()`
```

Answer (score 1):

you have to used spark-submit command to running you python script with spark (using command line terminal).

```
spark-submit  /home/sample.py
```

Comment: Thanks Sahil for your reply :) .I did  the same as you said Sahil.it is not throwing any error.But i could not  get the output.even i could not dataframe as well. I want to render the scatter graph by using JSON data (from mentioned url in code).Please help and guide on this. I am new to PYSpark.It will help me a lot.Thanks in advance